# email search failure

Tags: search, search-builder, advanced-search

I get this error when searching for any email address in advanced search or search builder.

https://pastebin.com/6LRJDyt1

The 1-address alias is not defined, so it fails. In advanced search it does not let me select the location type for the email. However, in search builder it does and it still fails. I tested this on the demo https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ and email search works there. I have disabled all civi extensions and it still fails.

WP 5.2.1 and Civi 5.13.4 multisite. Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Can you try if this pr works for you https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13399/files

Comment: I actually came upon that earlier and tried that patch but it gives a WP error saying, 'The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.'

Comment: did you ever solved this?

Comment: @DaveT, partially https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1128